# Booting straight into elementary (no GRUB shown) - expected or not?

Tags: system-installation

I recently reinstalled elementary OS and dedicated to it my entire hard drive (well, actually I left some unallocated space in case I want to test some other Linux-based operating system in the future). There were no kernel updates since the reinstall.

elementary now automatically boots up just fine without showing GRUB. So, my question is: is this behavior expected or not? Will GRUB show up once there's a kernel update? Should I worry about something or not?

Comment: please let me know my answer solved your question, also I edited my post as well =)

Answer (score 2):

This is 100% normal behavior since your computer only has one operating system. If you would like to show the GRUB menu during boot, type the following command into your terminal. This command will open up the `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub
```

Once you type in your administrator password and the text document opens, place a `#` symbol before the text `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

It should look like this:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Once you are done, open up terminal and type in `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

In the question there are two sub questions to answer.

1. > elementary now automatically boots up just fine without showing GRUB

This is normal behaviour. (since It  is not **dual boot** )

If no other operating system is detected GRUB will boot straight into the default operating system and **no menu** will be displayed.

If another operating system is detected the GRUB  menu will display.

Also elementary OS is configured on the system as the default, I think the 'wait timer' is so short that it'll default-boot into the latest kernel.

Menu will appear if you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during loading Grub.

To get GRUB menu permanentaly  you need to customize the `/etc/default/grub`

change settings  **GRUB_TIMEOUT=10**

and place a "#" symbol at the start of line GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Save changes and run `sudo update-grub` to apply changes

2. > Will GRUB show up once there's a kernel update

**No** .Kernel update never trigger grub to show menu at boot time, unless you do something to `/etc/default/grub` before and forgot to run `sudo update-grub`.

Also whenever kernels are updated, grub push the old kernels back to advanced options and keep new kernel as default main entry.

<sub>reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)</sub>